# Can you use Vital Strike with Focused Attack for crit build?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats

Can you use Vital Strike with Focus Attack?
Using a Rapier and having either Keen Enhancement or Imp Crit

Vital Strike make 1 attack at highest BAB deal double weapon dice in damage

> #### Focused Attack (Combat)
>
> **Prerequisite:** Base attack bonus +6.
>
> **Benefit:** When you take a full attack action, you can choose to make only one attack. This decision must be made before making your first attack. For every attack you could make but don’t, the critical threat range for the one attack you make increases by 1. This increase happens after all other adjustments to your critical threat range. Thus if you could make three melee attacks with a keen scimitar as a full attack, when you use Focused Attack you take a full attack action to make a single attack with a threat range of 13–20 (18–20 for a scimitar, 15–20 for a keen scimitar, 13–20 for giving up two attacks with Focused Attack and a keen scimitar).

Answer (score 9):

### No

Focused Attack requires you take the full-attack action. Vital Strike requires you take the attack action (a standard action, incompatible with the full-attack action's full-round action). Thus, the feats do not interact at all, and cannot be used at the same time.

Comment: It’s probably *not* worth complicating the answer, but the greatsword battler divine fighting technique allows you to use Vital Strike on a charge, so if you pounce... maybe (not by RAW but then no one runs pounce by RAW to begin with so maybe).